# Creating a price total table based on product checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a cart page with checkboxes on the left for each product which updates a row in a table to show the current price. The caveat is that because I am already using the input value for another piece of javascript, I can't just do a sum based on the  tag. I have this code, but it doesn't work and I can't tell why:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="29.99" onclick="calculate()">Product 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="29.99" onclick="calculate()">Product 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="29.99" onclick="calculate()">Product 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="29.99" onclick="calculate()">Product 4<br />
Total Price : $<div id="divid" style="color:red;"></div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function calculate() {
var el, i = 0;
var total = 0;
while(el = document.getElementsByName("chk")[i++]) {
if(el.checked) { total= total + Number(el.value);}
}
var div = document.getElementById('divid');
div.innerHTML = "Total : " +total ;
};
```

Is this the right direction? If not, how do I do this?

Here is my Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7hv00hf/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f7hv00hf/1/ working

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy what's the difference?

Comment: @Adjit script was not connected well to dom